# Equivalent AdaptiveAvgPool2d API in cuDNN

Tags: pytorch, cudnn

Is there an equivalent API in cuDNN as the `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` in Pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible. you can create the pooling descriptor.

here is the official documentation for the API-
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/api/index.html#cudnnPoolingMode_t